# Creating a function to print a different question based on the argument given

Tags: python

I'm creating a text game to learn the basics of python, it is basically a short quiz game to determine your game character.

I wanted the question to print as if they were being typed, like this:

```
In=list("What is your name? ")
for x in In:
    print(x, end='')
    stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)

print("\n")
```

Then I wondered if I could make a function that could print the correct question from a variable containing a list of questions based on the argument given to the function. If the argument given is "1" it would print question 1 and so on... I keep having to come back to functions, I find them one of the most confusing.

I tried the below code, thinking perhaps lists in lists, but then it prints both questions. I need a way to identify just one 'item' from the variable.

```
import time
from sys import stdout

def ask_question():
    for list in list_questions:
        for item in list:
            for x in item:
                print(x, end='')
                stdout.flush()
                time.sleep(0.1)


list_questions = [["What is your name?"], ["What is your age? "]]
```

Questions I am wondering (and will look into after sleeping on it, but thought I would put here anyway):

Is it possible to use something other than a list here? Strings are iterable, would they be in some way easier to use for this?

How do you identify a list within a list? Is the below format for strings?

```
print(list_questions[0,1])
```

Could a dictionary be used?

Is there a completely different, better way of doing this whole thing?

If anyone has an abundance of free time and wat to look over the whole text game (there are many, many problems to be found) feel free:

https://github.com/hyperblue1356/Radiant_text_game/blob/main/code

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dict, containing all the questions that are linked to the variables.

```
questionsdict = {1: "What is your name?", 2: "What is your age?"}
```

You can then iterate over the characters to create the typing effect that you envision.

```
for char in questionsdict[question_no]:
    print(char, end="")
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

To wrap it all in a function, you need a function that accepts the value that relates to a question.

```
import time

def ask_question(question_no):
    questionsdict = {1: "What is your name?", 2: "What is your age?"}
    for char in questionsdict[question_no]:
        print(char, end="")
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

You can then call `ask_question(1)` or `ask_question(2)` to get either of the two questions printed out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with this:

```py
import time
from sys import stdout

def ask_question(q):
    for c in q:
         print(c, end='')
         stdout.flush()
         time.sleep(0.1)
    return input()


i = ask_question("What is your name? ")
print(i)
```

This treats the string of the question text as an iterable which is printed 'slowly'.

You just then need to think about having a list of questions:

```py
list_questions = ["What is your name? ", "What is your age? "]

i = ask_question(list_questions[1])
print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are new with functions so here you go:

Here I created a list containing some questions and a function ask(n) where n is the argument which takes the list index and print the question associated with that index.

```
ques=['whats your name?','your age?','your fav food','your country']
def ask(n):
    print(ques[n])
    x=input('Answer: ')
```

To be more specific you can also use a dictionary to store the questions. This time if we call the function ask with 1 as the parameter, "**ask(1)**" then the value associated with 1  which is "whats your name" in the question dictionary will be raised.

```
ques={1:'whats your name?',2:'your age?',3:'your fav food',4:'your country'}
def ask(n):
    print(ques[n])
    x=input('Answer: ')
```

You can also raise a random question from your question bank by using **random.randint()**

```
import random
ques={1:'whats your name?',2:'your age?',3:'your fav food',4:'your country'}
def ask():
    n=random.randint(1,4)
    print(ques[n])
    x=input('Answer: ')
```